# uline doesn't show at the end of line

Tags: ulem

Here is the minimal working example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ulem} 
\begin{document}
one two three  one two three one two three one two three one two three one two three one two three one two three 

one two three one two three one two three one two three one two three \uline{\hspace{5em}}  %no underline showing
\end{document}
```

the result is

[image]

However, there should be a underline of 5em length. Is it a bug of `ulem` package?

Comment: Use `\uline{\phantom{\hspace{5em}}}` or `\uline{\hspace{5em}{}}`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Hi, ChristianHupfer. I can confirm phantom works. But `\uline{\hspace{5em}{}}` is not working

Comment: @campa: I don't understand it at the moment, so it's better not to post an answer. On the other hand, `\hspace{5em} Foo` won't print a space of the given width and then `Foo` (i.e. omitting the `\uline` command) -- I assume it's the `\hskip` which underlies `\hspace`

Comment: @campa Hi, campa. Why you delete answer of `\hspace*` which works. So your new comment shows a new bug of `ulem`?

Comment: @user15964: yes, the `{}` doesn't work (it worked, but under different circumstances

Comment: @campa: `\hskip ... ` dies out at the end of a line, as I can confirm now. I assume, that this leads to an empty box at the end of a line and as such `\uline` does nothing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behaviour seems as you should expect, with `\uline{\hspace` producing the same space as `\hspace` but underlined

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ulem} 
\begin{document}
one two three  one two three one two three one two three one two three one two three one two three one two three 

one two three one two three one two three one two three one two three \uline{\hspace{5em}}  %no underline showing



one two three one two three one two three one two three one two three \uline{\hspace{5em}}  %no underline showing



one two three one two three one two three one two three one two three \hspace{5em}x1

one two three one two three one two three one two three one two three \uline{\hspace{5em}}x2 

one two three one two three one two three one two three one two three \hspace*{5em}x3 

one two three one two three one two three one two three one two three \uline{\hspace*{5em}}x4 
\end{document}
```

Normally a space is discarded at a linebreak, so the left margin is preserved, so you see this happening for x1 and x2, `\hspace*` forces the space to be kept so you see the space in x3 and x4, underlined in the x4 case.